# subnav hover keep the style of main nav

Tags: css, nav

I am trying to restyle the navigation bar on the following website.
The website use Bootstrap and a navbar as main navigation and a navbar-subnav as a secondary one.
Even though i dont have a problem styling the two navs, it seems i can style the hover state of the subnav.
Whatever i try it keeps the same hover state with the main navigation.

here is the page: https://www.suug.co.uk/sustainabilityhub/test2017/

the Societies/Sports etc is the main one, and the test2017 is the secondary one

thank you

Comment: it i because both navbar have navbar class so if you make changes to CSS of navbar then obviously it l reflect to both. Assign an id or unique class to both the navbar

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understood your question but to style elements differently you have to have a selector that matches only one of your elements and make the differences there.